# iPhone NSKeyedArchiver - the data saved with this class persist after app update via AppStore?

Tags: iphone, nskeyedarchiver

I am a newbie in the iPhone dev and I want to know if I will save some data(NSSDictinary) with NSKeyedArchiver, tis data persist after an update process of my app via AppStore?
Let's say that I want to save user an pass for my app and probably this information will be saved into the app folder.If I will update the app via AppStore with iTunes, the old data saved are still there?The user will find his saved login credentials?

Thanks,

Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `NSUserDefaults` to store such settings. It will write the information to a directory that will be preserved accross syncing, restoring a backup and application upgrades.

Alternatively you can use the Keychain to store the username/password. This is more secure, and it will also survive application updates or syncing / restoring a backup.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you save the data to the app's document directory (using [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:toFile:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSKeyedArchiver/archiveRootObject:toFile:)).

> **Files Saved During Application Updates**
>   Updating an application replaces the
>   previous application with the new one
>   downloaded by the user. During this
>   process, iTunes installs the updated
>   application in a new application
>   directory. It then moves the user’s
>   data files from the old installation
>   over to the new application directory
>   before deleting the old installation.
>   Files in the following directories are
>   guaranteed to be preserved during the
>   update process:
>
> /Documents
>   /Library/Preferences
>   Although files in other user
>   directories may also be moved over,
>   you should not rely on them being
>   present after an update.

[Getting Paths to Application Directories](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/FilesandNetworking/FilesandNetworking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH21-SW6)

Comment: Thank you very much guys.

I really appreciate you help.

Alex.

Comment: The new data storage guidelines for iOS 5+ suggests to not save in documents directory if you can recreate the data. Everything else will be uploaded to iCloud - which is not always what you want